# When does equality holds in the given problem?

Tags: inequality

Let $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ be non zero real numbers with $a_1a_2\dots a_n=c$, and let $a_1^2+a_2^2+\dots+a_n^2\le n|c|^{\frac{2}{n}}$.
I think equality holds if and only if $|a_1|=|a_2|=\dots=|a_n|$. I am not able to prove this. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement reduces to the [arithmetic-geometric mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), for which you can find a proof [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Proofs_of_the_AM.E2.80.93GM_inequality).
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2\geq \sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^n a_i^2}$$
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2\geq \sqrt[n]{c^2}$$
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2\geq |c|^{n/2}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2\geq n |c|^{n/2}$$